# Show own application in share dialog in iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c

Show my own application in share dialog in iPhone just like screenshot you can go in photo and click on share then you see Facebook, mail,  Twitter etc. i want to show my app icon "weibo"]
please reply ???

[image]

[image]

Comment: follow this tutorial: http://goo.gl/NKqrWk it can help you.

Comment: Actually i want to show my own app in share menu, when i share my photo gallery image ,then i want to show my own app icon in share menu like Facebook,twitter .

Comment: you can see the new attached images

Answer (score 0):

If only [Googling for that turned up a result on the Apple developer site](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1587/_index.html). You need to define a type identifier for your data, then declare it as imported.

Comment: I did that, but it's not working for me,can you give me another thing?

Comment: If your 'data' is a standard image file type, it won't appear in all the Apple apps share sheets, just Mail and Messages. There's nothing you can do about it.